# Как проверить ячейки на наличие чисел и вывести их суммы?

Tags: python, excel

Имеется файл формата .xlsx
Задача: вычислить сумму чисел, заключенных в данном столбце
Проблема: при наличии в столбце чего-то кроме числа, подсчет невозможен
Не могу понять, как можно поставить проверку ячейки на наличие числа?

Что уже есть:

```
import openpyxl

rb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/путь_к_файлу/TestData.xlsx')
sheet = rb['Sheet1'] 

len_var = column_len(sheet,4)
cell = 0

for i in range(1,len(sheet['C'])):                          # Пробег по всему столбцу
                                                            # Если в ячейке число, то закидывать его в сумму
    if (sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).?????):             # Как поставить проверку на наличие в ячейке числа?
        cell+= float(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).value) # Суммируем числа в ячейках третьего столбца

print (cell)
```

Comment: `if isinstance(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3),(float, int))`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin заменил строку, почему-то показывает в итоге 0. Код не менял, только добавил строку, которую Вы предложили

Comment: возможно все данные хранятся как строки ?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin В этом файлике в столбце есть числа. Но иногда попадаются всякие левые объекты, типа случайно нажатой ерунды

Comment: попробуйте написать `.isdigit()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

с вашим же кодом используя `isinstance`

```
import openpyxl

rb = openpyxl.load_workbook('TestData.xlsx')

sheet = rb['Sheet1'] 
cell = 0
for i in range(1,len(sheet['C'])+1):
    if isinstance(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).value,(float, int)): # проверка на тип int/float
         cell+= sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).value # Суммируем числа в ячейках третьего столбца

print (cell)
```

или просто `try/except`

```
import openpyxl

rb = openpyxl.load_workbook('TestData.xlsx')

sheet = rb['Sheet1'] 
cell = 0

for i in range(1,len(sheet['C'])+1):
    
    try :    
        cell+= float(sheet.cell(row = i, column = 3).value)
    except:
        pass

print(cell)
```

Comment: Возможно несовместимость сред разработки, но у меня почему-то опять 0 показывает... Работаю на Debian в Eclipse

Comment: @Enoch с вашим фалом с яндекс диска все работает хорошо.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все заработало

Answer (score 7):

Воспользуйтесь модулем Pandas - он сделает за вас всю "грязную" работу:

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas | conda install pandas

filename = "/Downloads/TestData.xlsx"
# читаем/парсим Excel файл в Pandas.DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
# df.iloc[:, 2] - выбираем третий столбец по индексу (индексация начинается с нуля)
# функция `pd.to_numeric(column, errors="coerce")` пытается преобразовать все значения столбца в числа, 
# если это невозможно заменяет значения на `NaN` (Not a Number)
res = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 2], errors="coerce").sum()
print(f"Сумма значений столбца 2 (нумерация начинается с нуля): {res}")
```

вывод:

```
Сумма значений столбца 2 (нумерация начинается с нуля): 16.75
```

PS функция [pd.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) по умолчанию ожидает в первой строке Excel файла наименования столбцов и в таком случае к столбцам DataFrame удобнее обращаться по имени - `df["column_name"]`

PPS [Tutorial: "10 minutes to Pandas"](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)

Comment: К сожалению, не работает. Сообщение raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 3

Comment: @Enoch, что выводит df.dtypes ?

Comment: @Enoch, я бы мог привести полностью проверенное решение если вы выложите небольшой воспроизводимый Excel файл на файлообменник и выложите ссылку на него

Comment: да конечно. Вот тренировочный файл https://transfiles.ru/k43wg Так подойдет?

Comment: вот еще с яндекс диска https://yadi.sk/i/YFcZwddmt0lkZw

Comment: @Enoch, исправил ответ и проверил его на вашем тренировочном файле)

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает! Можете ли только еще подсказать суть этой конструкции? (df.iloc[:, 2], errors="coerce")

Comment: @Enoch, добавил комментарии с пояснениями в ответ...

Comment: Спасибо за подробный комментарий!